# why does rails caching check the URL on every page request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis

I'm currently using redis-store, but I'm pretty sure this is Rails' doing and not redis-store's.

On *every request* I see items like this in the cache log:

```
1339188014.237987 (db 1) "get" "cache:http://www.domain.com/?"
1339188107.318145 (db 1) "get" "cache:https://www.domain.com/login?"
```

(two separate requests)

I am only using fragment caching ( <% cache 'some_key' do %>...<% end %> )

I am *not* using page caching or action caching.

So, why would rails be looking at those keys?  I can find no trace of setting those keys, and I've verified that they're nil.

Answer (score 1):

Look in:

```
gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/cache.rb
```

in your ruby directory (if you don't know where this is and are on UNIX/Mac you can type `which ruby` on the command line to find the bin directory and then go up from there.)

Throw a breakpoint in there and debug it to see the call stack. That log is coming from line 526 in `ActiveSupport::Cache::Store#log`

When i debugged this, i found that it's related to Metal and it's looking for a completely cached version of the page. It seems pretty harmless, and if you're not actually doing page caching, nothing bad will probably ever happen from it.